# I can not install manuelbastionilab from file

Tags: installation

I downloaded it to desktop, Opened Blender,User Preference,Addons, Open from file,select manuelbastionilab file, and it just isnt working.I have been trying off and on for two days now with no luck.Can some one help please?
Here are a few screen shots on some out comes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't have to extract the files, the installation is made with zip file.

Answer (score 1):

"Install from file" expects the downloaded ZIP file.

[image]